# Can't use package in Julia

Tags: jupyter-notebook, package, julia

Here is my code. I type all code in jupyter notebook.

[image]

I can use package normally last week. During the week, I didn't do anything in Julia. I don't know what happened. How can I solve this problem?

Does it mean that as long as I have downloaded the
package before in jupyter notebook, I will never have to download it again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually you don't need to add that two packages, as they are in the Julia Standard Library, i.e. they are shipped with Julia itself. Just _use_ them...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, once you download a package, it is saved into a specific environment. So assuming you don't switch Julia versions or create / activate a new environment, you will always have the packages you previously installed accessible to you.

You can double check what is installed in your current env by doing `Pkg.status()`.